# How to pass escape characters as command line parameters using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, escaping, command-line-interface

I wrote a python script needed 2 command line arguments, and there are some `'&'`s in the 2nd parameter. And I received the error zsh parse error near &', so I tried to quoted and double-quoted these 2 parameters but the result went wrong. The code is simplified as below:

```
import base64, hmac, urllib, sys  
from hashlib import sha256  
def signature(secret_access_key, string_to_sign):  
    h = hmac.new(secret_access_key, digestmod=sha256)
    h.update(string_to_sign)
    sign = base64.b64encode(h.digest()).strip()  
    return urllib.quote_plus(sign)  
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    secret_access_key = 'a'  
    string_to_sign = 'b\nc\nd&e&f'  
    print signature(secret_access_key, string_to_sign)  
    print signature(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])  
    print sys.argv[2] == string_to_sign
```

and following is the configuration in pycharm
[image]
`print sys.argv[2] == string_to_sign` returned `False` and
The result of `signature(secret_access_key, string_to_sign)` is what I expected, but I need to pass these 2 parameters in command line.
So is there any way to escape `'&'` and `'\n'` in command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include literal newlines; you could use `$''` in bash, zsh:

```
$ python -c'import sys; print(sys.argv)' a $'b\nc\nd&e&f'
['-c', 'a', 'b\nc\nd&e&f']
```

If you want two characters: backslash + `n` then drop `$`:

```
$ python -c'import sys; print(sys.argv)' a 'b\nc\nd&e&f'
['-c', 'a', 'b\\nc\\nd&e&f']
```

Comment: This is the output I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to put quotes around your input parameters:

```
python yourscript.py "a" "b\nc\nd\&ef"
```

and change your script to replace the string `"\n"` with a carriage return:

```
import base64, hmac, urllib, sys  
from hashlib import sha256  
def signature(secret_access_key, string_to_sign):  
    h = hmac.new(secret_access_key, digestmod=sha256)
    h.update(string_to_sign)
    sign = base64.b64encode(h.digest()).strip()  
    return urllib.quote_plus(sign)  
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    secret_access_key = 'a'  
    string_to_sign = 'b\nc\nd&e&f'    
    input_argument = sys.argv[2].replace(r'\n','\n')
    print signature(secret_access_key, string_to_sign)  
    print signature(sys.argv[1], input_argument)      
    print input_argument == string_to_sign
```

This gives as output:

```
iF5JXP343nGyFhcagBhVDVDSnECQpHDMnuq%2F6ryFzBc%3D
iF5JXP343nGyFhcagBhVDVDSnECQpHDMnuq%2F6ryFzBc%3D
True
```

Comment: I tried quoted and double-quoted these 2 parameters in CLI but the results are different, so is the result of `print sys.argv[2], string_to_sign`

Comment: Did you escape your `string_to_sign` value as well ?

Comment: There is no need to escape `string_to_sign` ,because non escape `string_to_sign` is exactly what I need.

Comment: But `iF5JXP343nGyFhcagBhVDVDSnECQpHDMnuq%2F6ryFzBc%3D` is the result I want. I can get this without escaping `string_to_sign`

Comment: In that case you need to quote your input parameter and replace the string `\n` with a carriage return, see updated answer